# Trying to build phonon4qt5

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, qt5, phonon

i'm started to port a pretty big app from qt 4.8 to qt5.3 (osx). This app uses phonon.
I know that phonon is deprecated and maybe ill replace it in the future but for now i want to make my app to work in 5.3 as fast as possible so i downloaded the kde-phonon lib, and following this: http://api.kde.org/kdesupport-api/phonon-apidocs/phonon/html/phonon4qt5.html
i tried to compile it as it follows:

> sudo cmake .. -DPHONON_BUILD_PHONON4QT5=ON
>   -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/its/Qt/5.3/clang_64 -DPHONON_INSTALL_QT_EXTENSIONS_INTO_SYSTEM_QT=ON

But i'm getting this output:

> ---
>
> -- The following external packages were located on your system.
>   -- This installation will have the extra features provided by these packages.
>   + Qt5 Core (qtbase)
>   + Qt5 Gui (qtbase)
>   + Qt5 Widgets (qtbase)
>   + OpenGL
>   + Qt5 DBus (qtbase)
>   + Qt5 Designer (qttools)
>   + Qt5 OpenGL (qtbase)
>   + Qt5 Declarative (qtquick1)
>   + PulseAudio
>   + GLib2
>
> Congratulations! All external packages have been found.
>
> ---
>
> -- Configuring done CMake Error at cmake/FindPhononInternal.cmake:153 (add_library):   Cannot find source file:
>
> MACOSX_BUNDLE
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
>   .hpp   .hxx .in .txx Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   cmake/PhononMacros.cmake:33 (automoc4_add_library)
>   designer/CMakeLists.txt:12 (phonon_add_designer_plugin)

So yeah, i'm pretty stuck. Does Anyone have an idea of this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to check line no 153 of FindPhononInternal.cmake and see if the source file MACOSX_BUNDLE (this may be defined as a variable in the file) is present or not.

Comment: This is the line:         add_library(${_target_NAME} ${_add_executable_param} ${ARGN})

Comment: Try to print all these variables in log like message(this is target ${_target_NAME}), others like message(this is parameter ${_add_executable_param})  for better clarity. The mains issue is about the source file not found, try to find what is the name of the file it is searching and then try locating it

Comment: Did you find out the solution?